# вызов события change из метода для input

Tags: javascript, события, input, javascript-events, onchange

Столкнулся с такой вот задачей - есть функция конструктор, `InputElement()` которая создает input. В объекте есть два метода

```
InputElement.prototype.onChange = function(callback){
    elem.addEventListener('change', callback);
}  

InputElement.prototype.setValue = function(inputedValue){
    elem.value = inputedValue;          
    return elem;
}
```

как в методе setValue вызвать коллбэк из onChange, чтоб сработало такое условие:

```
    let result;
    let input= new InputElement();
    input.onChange(() => result = 'A');
    input.setValue('B');
    console.log(result)// -> A
```

Был вариант с установкой атрибута disabled для элемента после события change, но не сработало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function InputElement() {
  this.elem = document.createElement("input");
  document.body.appendChild(this.elem);
}

InputElement.prototype.setValue = function(value) {
  this.elem.value = value;
  this.elem.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
  return this.elem;
}

InputElement.prototype.onChange = function(callback) {
  this.elem.addEventListener('change', callback);
}

let result;
let input = new InputElement();
input.onChange(() => result = 'A');
input.setValue('B');
console.log(result) // -> A
```

Comment: В таком случае просто вызов метода inputElement.setValue('B') не сработает

Comment: @Martin Я ничего не понял. Что должно "сработать", и что "не срабатывает"?

Comment: @Martin Я Вам сейчас за такое объяснение минус поставлю. Вам знаком знак препинания "точка"?

Comment: есть два метода: onChange должен при вызове проходить тест inputElement.onChange(() => result = 100) -> 100 - этот код выполняется;
метод setValue соответственно проходит тест  inputElement.setValue('B') -> B - этот код выполняется.
Но если вызвать сначала onChange а потом setValue, то результат должен быть как в тесте, то есть метод setValue должен вызвать onChange и в инпуте должно остаться значение которое стало там поле события change